# Trying to build angular 5 app. Error: Can't resolve 'tslib' in '/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to build an Angular 5 app using 
`ng build --prod`. But the following errors are always thrown.

```
ERROR in /home/prashanth/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subject.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tslib' in '/home/prashanth/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5'
ERROR in /home/prashanth/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/InnerSubscriber.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tslib' in '/home/prashanth/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5'
ERROR in /home/prashanth/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js
```

and repeats for all the other directories in the rxjs folder.

I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

I am using Lubuntu 17.10 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing node modules directory

`rm -rf node_modules`

Then re install npm packages.

`npm install`

Comment: Thanks. The build succeeded.